# How to sign an xml with XADES4j, certificate store windows and Smart Card + PIN Code

Tags: java, xml, xades4j, gemalto

I'm trying to sign an xml file using the XADES4j. I also use the smart card certification (will be loaded from the windows store).

Is there an example that meet my search because i'm new with XML signature and smart cards. I searched a fix for few weeks without success.

There are others example about it but it's not very clear :

[Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958819/signing-document-with-qualified-certificate-smart-card)
[Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203789/trying-to-sign-pdf-with-a-smart-card)

I found this demonstration at https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningKeyingData, but I don't know how to set the function `PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider` to apply the Windows certificate parameters and their pin code:

```
    KeyingDataProvider kp = new PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
              "path/to/native/lib",
               "MS SABRI", // CERTIFICATE NAME
               new FirstCertificateSelector(),
               null, 
               null,false);,
```

My code:

```
          try {

     // >>> TEST N°1
     // KeyingDataProvider kp = new DirectKeyingDataProvider((X509Certificate) certExemple, PrivateKEY);

      // >>> TEST N°2
      KeyingDataProvider kp = new PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
              "path/to/native/lib",
               "name", // CERTIFICATE NAME
               new FirstCertificateSelector(),
               new DirectPasswordProvider("123456"), // PIN CODE
               new DirectPasswordProvider("123456"), // PIN CODE
               false);



      // XADES
      XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp);
      XadesSigner signer    = p.newSigner();

      javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory factory = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = null;
      builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();


      // XML FILE TO BE SIGNED
      Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File("FileNotSigned.xml"));

      // NODE
      Node parentElement            = doc1.getDocumentElement();
      Node nodeToSign               = doc1.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild();
      Node nodeToAttachSignature    = doc1.getDocumentElement();


      IndividualDataObjsTimeStampProperty dataObjsTimeStamp = new IndividualDataObjsTimeStampProperty();
      AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty globalCommitment    = AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty.proofOfApproval();
      CommitmentTypeProperty commitment                     = CommitmentTypeProperty.proofOfCreation();   

      // XPATH STRING
      String xpathHeader    ="/InvoiceHeader";
      String xpathBody      ="/InvoiceBody";

      // OBJECT
      DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference("");
      obj1.withTransform(XPath2Filter.intersect( xpathHeader ).intersect(xpathBody));
      SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects( obj1 );

      // SIGN
      signer.sign(dataObjs, nodeToAttachSignature);

      // TRANSFORMER
      Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

      // XML SIGNED
      Result output = new StreamResult(new File("FileSigned.xml"));
      Source input  = new DOMSource(doc1);
      transformer.transform(input, output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Windows store + smart card" as both seem exclusive. Anyway, ff you want to use a smart card, you code is almost OK.

Smart cards usually have a native library that is installed on the host OS. On the first argument of `PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider` you should pass the path to that library. The second parameter (`name`) is just the name to register the instance of the provider. Since the smart card usually handles the PIN to access the key, you usually can supply `null` for the `keyStorePasswordProvider` and `entryPasswordProvider` arguments.

On the library unit tests you can find an [example using the Portuguese citizen card](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/test/java/xades4j/production/SignerTTest.java#L106).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Luis for your help.
I managed to do the signing successfully. But when checking xml file from the certificate provider, he sent me this answer: "Error during securityController: java.lang.String can not be cast to java.security.cert.X509Certificate". Can you tell me the cause of this error? and how can we solve it?
Thank you again Luis.

Comment: The exception seems pretty obvious.. form the stack trace you should be able to find the code line that is causing that problem.. Doesn't seem to be a problem with xades4j, but let me know if it is.

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to be a problem with xades4j. I deleted the <ds: X509IssuerSerial> block and the problem is solved. I still have other signature verification issues (certificate provider side) and I am still checking them out.Example: I have to keep a single reference in the signature block (reference that I created contains the XPATH2), so must eliminate the code that creates the automatic reference that gathers to the block SignedProperties : normally it does not create problems is not it? . I am waiting for your help if I have encountered a blocking error soon ! Thanks again Luis.